# Rename files Pentaho Kettle

Tags: rename, filenames, pentaho, kettle

Please help! I have lots of pdf files (~6000). Now they are named with uniqueidentifier  datatype and located on my PC in folder. 
In database their names are in column File_ID. There are also columns File_type, First_name, Last_name
I need to rename files with new format "First_name Last_name File_type.pdf".
I created transformation in PDI and after lookup  I have filenames in needed format.
But what steps should I use to rename files?

Answer (score 2):

The rename step is at the job level and called `Move file`.

Answer (score 0):

one option would be using the [move files step](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Move+files) within a job, as AlainD suggests. Another option would be to create a batch file (.cmd, or a powershell script) that contains the necessary commands to rename all the files.